# Have done and have done or have done and done?

Tags: past-participles

I would like to say that I have done multiple things together. Should I use "I have done sth1 and have done sth2" or should I omit the second "have" and say " I have done sth1 and done sth2 "?

Thank you!

Comment: "I've washed the dishes, cleaned the floor and dusted the furniture."  No, you don't need to repeat _I have_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have done the sudoku and I have done the crossword.
>
> I have done the sudoku and done the crossword.
>
> I have done the sudoku and the crossword.

All are acceptable. The third is the most idiomatic in everyday speech. Unless there is some reason you want to emphasise the verb or the verb is necessary to convey the correct meaning, I would go with the third option.

The first one can be used to emphasise the 'I' and make it clear that it's you that has done everything. The only real example I can think of where this would be a common choice is an argument/ discussion about who of a group has done the things. For example, someone has done too many of the chores at home or too many of the tasks of a team at work. Although this could still be conveyed by emphasising the 'and' in the third option.

The second option is unnecessary and would only be used if the verb is specifically important.

So overall, I would stick with option 3 in nearly all cases

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use  **I have done** sth1 and sth2.

We can also say '**I have done** sth1 and **I have done** sth2.' (for emphasis)

'I have done sth1 and done sth2' does not sound good.